# spring rest controller with and without callable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

First I wrote simple spring REST controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/id", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDetails(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
       // wrote logic for JSON response....
}
```

Second we need to improve the performance so I wrote controller using Callable like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/id", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getDetails(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
          return new Callable<String>(){
          @Override
          public String call() throws Exception {
           // ...
          return "someJSONString";
         }
       }
    }
```

Now the problem is when I compare the performance using JMETER for both above methods I dont see any major differences.

So do I miss anything while writing Callable controller?

Comment: And why should it, you are creating a `Callable` and then what? If you aren't passing it to anything that can execute it in a a-synch way nothing is going to happen. So if you only construct it and call the call method yourself, you haven't gained anything.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum ..so how I write that execute it in a-synch way? pls help

Comment: There are many mechanisms like Agents (Akka) or Fibers, but the truth is that if you are willing to return some outcome, it won't speed up much (if anything) for single request, it can only have better handling of high load. Also, asynch is by some people considered "dirty" as it works as long as you won't run into bottleneck. Therefore I'd recomend you look into lightweight threads (for example fibers.io).

Comment: By passing the constructed callable to a `TaskExecutor`... But why so complex? Simply return the `Callable` from the `getDetails` method. If your only intend is to call something async then simply annotate the method you are calling with `@Async` instead of trying to hack around with your own constructed callable.

Comment: _"Second we need to improve the performance so I wrote controller using Callable"_  - And how exactly should that improve the performance? What performance metrics do you expect to change?

Comment: @M.Deinum I wrote @ Async controller but the browser complete the response and the controller is yet to complete the processing.

Comment: @zeroflagL I want to increase request/second served by server, I want to increase the throughput.

Comment: That would work, if the workload is IO bound, e.g. database queries. And as M.Deinum wrote the operation needs to be executed asynchronously. Then the server can take new requests while it's waiting for the operation to finish.

Answer (score 1):

you can not improve single request performance with using Callable interface, it helps to take more request in some cases. If your response type would be void, you can use runnable instead of callable, so with using runnable you can improve single request response time. For example, if your service is suitable for fork/join framework try it.